# WebAudio graph order

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Consider a graph consisting of a source, filter, gain node and destination. The nodes can be connected in two different ways:

```
source → gain node → filter → destination
```

*vs*

```
source → filter → gain node → destination
```

I can't hear any difference in sound. *Is* there any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular example, no, there shouldn't be.  Web Audio uses floating point, so there is far less potential for clipping (the main reason you might have chosen one over the other in an integer-based system; pragmatically speaking, there's zero real-world difference in your two signal paths.